# C++ Mysql Connector requires boost

Tags: c++, mysql, boost

General Information:

Windows 7 x86

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008

Mysql 5.6

Mysql Connector C++ 1.1.3

I'm trying to create simple C++ application that works with mysql database. I downloaded and installed mysql and mysql c++ connector.

Also I have configured visual studio for dynamic library as described in this article:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html

Than I follow this example:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-connecting.html

But when I try to compile application I get error:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 1.1.3\include\cppconn/connection.h(31) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/variant.hpp': No such file or directory
```

So, does mysql connector uses Boost libraries? On official mysql website there is non information about boost is required.

How to resolve that problem? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, current versions require boost. From a comment [at this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html):

> The boost libraries are now required. Install the boost libraries (from http://www.boostpro.com/download/) and remember to update 'Additional Include Directories' to point to where you installed the boost libraries.

There are more trouble-shooting tips in that comment thread.